# Use the same export attribute for all src-blocks

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I have a bunch of org files with many src-blocks. I use the same [exporter](https://github.com/DamienCassou/ox-linuxmag-fr/) (that I wrote) on every org file. Most src-blocks set the same `ATTR_LINUXMAG-FR` exporter attribute value:

```
#+ATTR_LINUXMAG-FR: :type console
#+begin_src text
foo
#+end_src
```

I'm tired of repeating this first line for 90% of my src-blocks. Is there a way to specify this export attribute once in a `.dir-locals.el` file and only override it where necessary? The above would then become simply:

```
#+begin_src text
foo
#+end_src
```

My `.dir-locals.el` file already specifies a value for `org-babel-default-header-args:text` and `org-babel-default-header-args:sh`. It doesn't look like this is the right place to put exporter attributes.

Comment: I don't know of a way to use local variables for this: "affiliated" keywords like `#+ATTR_...` are supposed to go with the object they modify (not even an empty line can intervene), so it is difficult to imagine a mechanism that would work. What I can suggest is a template system (I don't think you can do it with Org's own [structure templates](https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Templates.html) any longer, more's the pity. But you might be able to use `yasnippet` or something similar.